# How to display error messages in Trigger.io catalyst?

Tags: console, trigger.io, catalyst, error-logging

I am using Trigger.io to deploy my application. I am also using catalyst as my debugging tool http://trigger.io/catalyst/.

The issue I am facing is that in the debug console, errors don't seem to be registered

For instance, I deliberately created an error in my js file

[image]

However when I check the console in catalyst, no error is displayed

[image]

Do I need to alter any configuration for errors to be shown in catalyst?

Comment: Catalyst I don't think will recognize the forge.logging.log command.

Have you tried console.log instead?

Console.log should display the error message

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately iOS devices do not report Javascript errors, and errors that prevent the script from being run at all cannot be captured by Catalyst.

When you run your app the Trigger Toolkit runs a check of the javascript files in your app and should output warnings for errors such as this. Alternatively if you try running your app on Android you should see errors output in the Toolkit for this kind of Javascript error.